# JSON to http-form fields for Volley on Android

Tags: android, json, http

I have JSON of form.

```
{  
   "music":[  
      {  
         "acrid":"65468a1a4d0cc5c14b058b81783803b8",
         "artists":[  
            {  
               "name":"bond"
            }
         ],
         "title":"Explosive",
         "genres":[  
            {  
               "name":"Classical"
            },
            {  
               "name":"Jazz"
            }
         ],
         "external_ids":{  
            "isrc":"GBBBA0343510",
            "upc":"028947678472"
         },
         "album":{  
            "name":"The Classical Album 2005"
         },
         "duration_ms":"190360",
         "release_date":"2005-01-01",
         "label":"Universal Music Ireland Ltd.",
         "result_from":3,
         "external_metadata":{  
            "youtube":{  
               "vid":"HiaOFOMPOBc"
            },
            "spotify":{  
               "track":{  
                  "id":"0anmeZi9dLi00ZI4iBikOK"
               },
               "artists":[  
                  {  
                     "id":"3G4zK7ipHdaAZkG6EBwIoW"
                  }
               ],
               "album":{  
                  "id":"3IOUjGF4HmHXVMCur0VYUm"
               }
            },
            "itunes":{  
               "track":{  
                  "id":1104915761
               },
               "artists":[  
                  {  
                     "id":723736030
                  }
               ],
               "album":{  
                  "id":1104914378
               }
            },
            "musicstory":{  
               "track":{  
                  "id":"1540446"
               }
            },
            "deezer":{  
               "track":{  
                  "id":2513417
               },
               "genres":[  
                  {  
                     "id":98
                  }
               ],
               "artists":[  
                  {  
                     "id":8109
                  }
               ],
               "album":{  
                  "id":246770
               }
            }
         },
         "play_offset_ms":98273
      }
   ],
   "timestamp_utc":"2015-07-01 14:44:37"
}
```

I need to use convert it to map of form

```
data[music][acrid]=65468a1a4d0cc5c14b058b81783803b8"
data[music][album][name]=bond
....
data[music][genres][][name]=Classical
data[music][genres][][name]=Jazz
...
```

to use as parameters in API request to server.
I'm using Volley on Android to send network requests so that's why I need Map to make request params.

How to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote 2 converter  functions:

```
 //add prefix to every map elemement
    public static Map<String,String> addPrefixToMap(Map<String,String> map,String prefix) {
        Map<String,String> result=new HashMap<>();
        for (String key:map.keySet()) {
            result.put(prefix+key,map.get(key));
        }
        return result;
    }

    /*
      ConvertS JSON to form which can be used as params for Volley HTTP posting
      Supported types:JSONObject, JSONArray,Integer,Long,Double,String
      .toString is called for everything else
      Exception handling is caller's responsibility
     */
    public static Map<String,String> encodeJSONToMapWithPrefix(JSONObject json,String prefix2) throws JSONException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Map<String,String> result=new HashMap<>();
        Iterator<String> keys = json.keys();
        String keyPrefix="";
        if (prefix2!=null) {
            keyPrefix=prefix2;
        }
        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            Object value= json.get(key);

            if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
                Map<String, String> r = encodeJSONToMapWithPrefix((JSONObject) value, keyPrefix + "[" + key + "]");
                result.putAll(r);

            } else if (value instanceof JSONArray) {
                JSONArray jarr=(JSONArray)value;
                for (int i=0;i<jarr.length();i++) {
                    Map<String, String> r = encodeJSONToMapWithPrefix(jarr.getJSONObject(i), keyPrefix + "[" + key + "][]");
                    result.putAll(r);
                }
            } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
                result.put(keyPrefix+"["+key+"]",Integer.toString((Integer)value));
            } else if (value instanceof Long) {
                result.put(keyPrefix+"["+key+"]",Long.toString((Long)value));
            } else if (value instanceof Double) {
                result.put(keyPrefix+"["+key+"]",Double.toString((Double)value));
            } else if (value instanceof String) {
                result.put(keyPrefix+"["+key+"]",(String)value);
            } else {
                result.put(keyPrefix+"["+key+"]",value.toString());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

It was easy after that, Volley's getParams functions is just

```
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

            try {
                JSONObject json=new JSONObject();
                json.put("music",musicItem);
                Map<String, String> mm=encodeJSONToMapWithPrefix(json,null);
                mm=Utils.addPrefixToMap(mm,"data");

                params.putAll(mm);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                CustomLog.logException(e);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                CustomLog.logException(e);
            }
            return params;
        }
```